# Use last Decembers headcount and create a new column called YearStartingHeadcount and have that same number populate for starting from January of 2023

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The problem I am facing is that I want to calculate annualized attrition and to do that I need to use December of 2022s headcount and create a new column called YearStartingHeadcount and have that same number populate for starting from January of 2023 to the end of the year.
Right now, I am using the lag function to get the number from January to populate for December, but I don't know how to do it for the rest of the column.

This is what I have tried to do

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
   Year_Month,
   SUBSTR(YEAR_MONTH, 1,4) AS Year,
  CAST(right(Year_Month,2)AS NUMBER) AS Month,
 Num_Voluntary_Terminations AS NumVolTerms,
 Headcount
FROM "HRD"."WORKER"."DD_LITHKRI"
),
 YearStartingHeadcount AS(
  SELECT
  NumVolTerms,
  Month,
  Year,
 Headcount,
 CASE
   WHEN Month= 1 THEN LAG(Headcount,1) OVER (ORDER BY Year ,Month) 
   When Year=2022 THEN NULL
   Else 1548
 END AS StartingYearHeadcount
 FROM CTE
 ),
```

With this code since I am hard coding it works but without it I get this result. SYH is the column I want to populate with 1548 for the rest of the year getting it from the 12/2022 headcount.

| Year | Month | SYH | Headcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 12 | NULL | 1548 |
| 2023 | 1 | 1548 | 1536 |
| 2023 | 2 | Null | 1523 |
| 2023 | 3 | Null | 1503 |

Expected result:

| Year | Month | SYH | Headcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 12 | NULL | 1548 |
| 2023 | 1 | 1548 | 1536 |
| 2023 | 2 | 1548 | 1523 |
| 2023 | 3 | 1548 | 1503 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery which returns all Dec headcounts:

```
with CTE as (
 SELECT
   CAST(SUBSTR(YEAR_MONTH, 1,4) as NUMBER) AS Yr,
   CAST(right(Year_Month,2) AS NUMBER) AS Mth,
   Headcount
FROM "HRD"."WORKER"."DD_LITHKRI"
)
select
     Yr
   , Mth
   , LyDec.Headcount as YearStartingHeadCount
   , TM.HeadCount
from 
   CTE TM
   
   left join
   (
    select 
        Yr
      , HeadCount
    from cte
    where Mth=12
    ) LYDec
  on LYDec.Yr=TM.Yr-1
```

You then `LEFT JOIN` your main query to this to get the headcount for previous year's headcount.

I don't have access to a Snowflake account (you haven't provided sample data, anyhow) so I couldn't test it. Do let me/us know if you encounter problems.